# Connecting to a database in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I feel like an absolute idiot. I've been trying to connect to a database I created for a few hours now and I can't seem to get it to connect. Here is my code.

```
string chooseMoodCmbBx = moodCmbBx.SelectedIndex.ToString();
        string source = "Data Source='E:\\Documents\\Database\\MyDatabase.sdf';" +
                        "Password='password';" +
                        "Persist Security Info=False;";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(source);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Succesfully Connected");
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? Do you get any error?

Comment: IF error then post the error message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an SDF file, meaning that you connect to a Sql Compact not to Sql Server. You need to use the classes in the namespace `System.Data.SqlServerCe`

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(source);
```

Also, I am not sure of this, but I think you don't need to have single quotes around values in the connection string

```
    string source = "Data Source=E:\\Documents\\Database\\MyDatabase.sdf;" +
                    "Password=password;" +
                    "Persist Security Info=False;";
```